# JAVA - class design for n-grams

Tags: java, class, n-gram

I'll start with an example:

*The end is near. I will end you.*

I want to disambiguate the string "end" using n-grams. So what I have now is:

```
abstract class Ngram {...}
public class Bigram extends Ngram {...}
public class Trigram extends Ngram {...}
```

*Bigram*: [the, end], [end, is]; [will, end], [end, you]
*Trigram*: [the, end, is], [end, is near]; [I, will, end], [will, end, you]

However, now I'm thinking that it may be a good idea to not just count Bigrams, Trigrams etc. in general, but also to distinguish between Bigrams with the ambiguous word AW at position=0 and those where AW is at position=1, Trigrams with AW at pos=0, 1, 2 etc,.

This would mean that I could create additional classes: instead of one class Bigram which represents all Bigrams found in the text, I could have

```
abstract class Bigram {...}
public class BigramWithAmbigWordAt0 extends Bigram {...}
public class BigramWithAmbigWordAt1 extends Bigram {...}
```

Now, my question(s):

1. is that too much? If I do it this way, I don't have to check the position of the AW when using Bigram objects; on the other hand, I get a lot of classes with little (additional) content.
2. Is there some sort of heuristic that helps me to "solve" this problem? 
   The code is supposed to be fast, readable, robust... what is the best way to do this? Some sort of greedy approach where you just keep creating classes as long as they add something new, however insignificant it might be?

Answer (score 3):

A single class should suffice. You just need variables in that class:

```
public class Ngram 
{
    public int n;
    public int ambiguousWordPosition;
    public String sentence;

    public Ngram(int n, int ambiguousWordPosition, String sentence)
    {
        this.n = n;
        this.ambiguousWordPosition = ambiguousWordPosition;
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }
}
```

Then you can disambiguate:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> disambiguate(String word)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();   
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
    int cutoff = n-1;  

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - cutoff; i++) {
        if(words[i + ambiguousWordPosition].equals(word)) {
            ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int j = i; j < i + cutoff; j++){
                inner.add(words[j]);
            }
            outer.add(inner);
        }
    }

    return outer;
}
```

**NOTE**: Treat this as pseudo code. I haven't tested it myself, but you should be able to get the idea

Comment: You'd better add the list of words as a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not totally sure of what you're doing, but it sounds best to probably use an N-gram class and send in N (the integer) and AW as parameters to a constructor. That would be a better design if you're planning to extend or re-use this.

Comment: This is what I have now, a Ngramfactory which creates Bigrams, Trigrams... depending on the integer n.

Comment: Bigram/Trigram/Quadgram (is that the word for it?) shouldn't be separate classes- I'd probably just use an Ngram class that takes in parameters and has methods. The logic is probably similar (if not identical) such that making separate classes isn't worth the effort.